# SSO Integration using Spring utility

Tags: single-sign-on, jasperserver

How to do SSO integration on *JasperReporst Server* with the help of Spring Utility?

I have tried [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-ldap-using-http-headers-jasperreports-server-51-sso-framework), but this is not working.